# Android recyclerview Dynamically Add and Remove Views using Java code

Tags: android, insert, android-recyclerview

I have a recylerview item as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/sample1"
        android:text="Sample1"/>

      <LinearLayout 
      android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:id="@+id/insertat">
      </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/sample2"
        android:text="Sample2"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

onclicking id `sample1` i want to insert a layout file sample3.xml inside linearlayout id `insertat`. sample3.xml is as follows

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/toinsert">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Sample1"
        android:id="@+id/sample3"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

in the onBindview i am trying this code

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
      PersonViewHolderplace vh3 = (PersonViewHolderplace) viewHolder;
      vh3.sample1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if(vh3.toinsert == null){
                            View hiddenInfo = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.sample3, vh3.insertat, false);
                            vh3.insertat.addView(hiddenInfo);
                        }

                    }
                });
 }

public static class PersonViewHolderplace extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    TextView sample1;
    LinearLayout insertat;
    LinearLayout toinsert;

PersonViewHolderplace(View itemView)
    {
     super(itemView);
     this.sample1 = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.sample1);   
     this.insertat = (LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.insertat);
     this.toinsert = (LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.toinsert);
    }
 }
```

I have 10 items in the recyclerview.

When i click on the sample1 of the first item in the recyclerview, the sample3 xml is inserted in the second item.

the sample3.xml is not getting inserted at the same item which is clicked. its inserted in someother item.

also i want to add only once, but it keeps adding multiple times in the same item even i used the condition (vh3.toinsert == null)